# mouseover not working as an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, arrow-functions

I have the function below:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "red");
})
```

However, I wanted to try writing it as an arrow function, so I found that this [tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/d3-js/example/27637/using--this--with-an-arrow-function) and got this:

```
.on("mouseover", (d, i, nodes) => {
    d3.select(nodes[i])
      .attr("fill", "red");
})
```

However, whenever I try running it, I keep getting an error that says `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nodes[i]')`.

I have also tried replacing `nodes` and just calling `this` but it seems that no matter what I try, arrow functions don't work here. I feel like it shouldn't be a version issue since I'm using v7 of d3. Can anyone explain what the issue is here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can copy your code straight into the fiddle from the tutorial you referenced and it works, so I don't think the problem is in that piece.  Can you set up your own fiddle so we can see more of the context?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently starting since v6, the arrow function solutions provided in the link above is no longer possible, according to this [discussion](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/263)

So now the current solution would be:

```
.on("mouseover", (d) => {
    d3.select(d.currentTarget)
      .attr("fill", "red");
})
```